# Under what conditions are $\left(A\times C\right)\sqcup\left(B\times C\right)$ and $\left(A\sqcup B\right)\times C$ isomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Working in a category having products (notation $\times$) and coproducts
(notation $\sqcup$) it is clear to me that a canonical arrow $w:\left(A\times C\right)\sqcup\left(B\times C\right)\to\left(A\sqcup B\right)\times C$
exists.

In an obvious way there are arrows $A\times C\to A\to A\sqcup B$
and $A\times C\to C$ leading to an arrow $u:A\times C\to\left(A\sqcup B\right)\times C$

Likewise there is an arrow $v:B\times C\to\left(A\sqcup B\right)\times C$
.

$w$ is the unique arrow characterized by $w\circ i_{1}=u$ and $w\circ i_{2}=v$.

Here $i_{1}:A\times C\to\left(A\times C\right)\sqcup\left(B\times C\right)$
and $i_{2}:B\times C\to\left(A\times C\right)\sqcup\left(B\times C\right)$
are injections.

However, I cannot find a general way back and that gives rise to my question:

> Is it possible to give specific conditions under which $w$ is an
>   invertible arrow?

Or more broadly:

> Under what conditions are $\left(A\times C\right)\sqcup\left(B\times C\right)$
>   and $\left(A\sqcup B\right)\times C$ isomorphic?

Another way to express it:

> When is there distributivity of product wrt coproduct up to isomorphisms?

---

**edit**

I should have done more effort to find this myself. Afterwards I found a [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_category) on Wikipedia. It is clear to me now that there is distibutivity if the category is cartesian closed. Nevertheless feel free to still answer my question (it is always a pleasure for me to reward). Also I add a new question and the topology tag.

> Is the category of topological spaces (which is not cartesian closed) a [distributive category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_category)?

Comment: The category of topological spaces is a distributive category, and the functor $-\times C$ even preserves infinite coproducts. It is obvious that the function $w:\coprod_i (A_i \times C) \to (\coprod_i A_i) \times C$ is bijective. Moreover, the homeomorphic image of $A_i \times C$ is open in $(\coprod_i A_i) \times C$. It follows easily that the map $w$ is open.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thank you very much. Actually this confirms what I suspected (and also relieves me). I needed a second opinion because did not completely trust myself in this. If you make your comment an answer then I will accept.

Comment: Oh, I thought your main question was still about conditions under which the product $-\times C$ preserves binary coproducts. But I see you are happy with Cartesian closedness as a sufficient condition. Actually, I don't think either that there is any weaker condition implying distributivity, at least not one which is famously known. So I'll make my comment an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product functor $- \times C: \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Top}$ preserves **all** coproducts. To see this, note that the canonical map
$$
\textstyle
w:\coprod_i (A_i \times C) \to (\coprod_i A_i) \times C
$$
is basically just the identity function, sending $(a,c)$ in $A_j\times C$ to the point $(a,c)$ where now the $a$ is regarded as an element of $\coprod A_i$. From this it is pretty obvious that $w$ is a bijection. It remains to show that $w$ is an open map. To this end, let $U$ be any open set in the domain. Then $U = \coprod_i U_i$ where $U_i = U \cap (A_i\times C)$. Then $w(U) = \coprod_i w(U_i)$. Since $U_i$ is open in $A_i \times C$, the restriction $w|_{A_i \times C}$ is an embedding, and $A_i \times C$ is open in $(\coprod_i A_i) \times C$, it follows that $w(U_i)$ is open and thus $w(U)$ is open.

Comment: I think that the bijectivity of the function can also be seen as a consequence of the fact that the category of sets is cartesian closed.

Comment: @drhab: Yes, funnily I was thinking of this when I wrote my comment, but then forgot about it when I wrote the answer :-)